# Overtaking a moving object in hyperbolic geometry.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, kinematics

Suppose that a sailboat $S$ moves in a straight line (geodesic) with constant speed $v$ in an infinite hyperbolic sea. You try to overtake that sailboat with a motorboat $M$ which has maximal speed $u$ and can follow any differentiable curve. Can you do it, given that $u > v$, but you cannot approach the sailboat to a distance less than $R$ ?

The hyperbolic sea has constant curvature $K = -1$ and by overtaking it is meant that there exist times $t_1 < t_2$ such that the points $M(t_1)$, $S(t_1)$, $S(t_2)$, $M(t_2)$ lie on a single straight line (geodesic) in this order. Constants $u, v, R$ are finite and positive.

I think that the answer is negative but I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not negative, but depends on whether $u > v \cosh R$. Can you see how the motorboat can overtake the sailboat in this case, and why the motorboat cannot overtake the sailboat otherwise?

Comment: Well, I thought that if $u$ is only slightly bigger then you can always catch up the sailboat from behind but never get infront of it, which would be quite counter-intuitive (and frustrating for the guy in the motorboat). Is that correct? I guess that $v \cosh R$ in your reply is the maximum speed of any point inside the disc D(S(t), R)? This would make it obvious why $u > v \cosh R$ is sufficient. But I still don't see a clear reason why it is also neccessary.

Comment: Consider the point in time where the line between motorboat and sailboat is orthogonal to the sailboat's trajectory.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. So, from the perspective of the sailboat, the motorboat cannot ever get past the orthogonal geodesic, because the flow in the opposite direction is too strong. Now I feel a bit ashamed because I did not expect the answer to be so simple.